# cycle tmux windows of the same name

Tags: linux, command-line, tmux, window

this question (to my knowledge) has not been asked before, yet would benefit anyone that uses tmux!
I tried searching github too for plugins etc, but no luck yet.

## What I'd like to achieve:

- Cycle between windows of the same name.

## Why?

Imagine you have 6 tmux windows, in the following order, status bar would look similar to this:

`[0:zsh][1:vim][2:zsh][3:vim][4:zsh][5:vim]`

If Im currently in window 0 (zsh):

- I would like to cycle between the 3 'zsh' windows (0,2,4)

If Im currently in window 1 (vim):

- I would like to cycle between the 3 'vim' windows (1,3,5)

This would allow you to cycle windows of the same type without having to re-order all your windows first (vim next to vim, zsh next zsh etc). **bliss!**

I have tried myself, but no success :(

Comment: Why do you want to cycle, rather than go directly to a particular one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I created a basic solution.

1. Save the following script as `_tmux-cycle-samename` and make it executable (`chmod +x _tmux-cycle-samename`).

   ```bsh
   #!/bin/sh

   if [ "$1" = "-r" ]; then filter=tac; else filter=cat; fi

   name="$(tmux display-message -p '#W' | sed 's|\(.\)|[\\\1]|g')"

   tmux select-window -t "$(
      tmux list-windows -F '#{window_active} #{window_id} #W' \
      | grep '^[01] @[0123456789]* '"$name"'$' | "$filter" \
      | awk '
         NR==1 {result=$2}
         { if (seen==1) {result=$2; exit} 
           seen=$1
         }
         END {print result}
      '
   )"
   ```

   The script retrieves the right name (`tmux display-message …`) and prepares the string (`sed …`), so when interpreted as regex later the name is matched literally. Then the script lists windows (`tmux list-windows …`), picks the matching ones (`grep …`), preserves or reverses the order (`cat` or `tac` from the expansion of `$filter`) and finds the next inactive window (`awk …`). Finally the found window is selected (`tmux select-window …`).
2. Add these to your `~/.tmux.conf`:

   ```
   bind-key -T prefix > run-shell '/full/path/to/_tmux-cycle-samename'
   bind-key -T prefix < run-shell '/full/path/to/_tmux-cycle-samename -r'
   ```

   If `_tmux-cycle-samename` can be resolved via `PATH` then you don't need to specify the full path.
3. If already inside `tmux` then run `tmux source-file ~/.tmux.conf`. A `tmux` server started anew will source the file automatically.
4. Try <kbd>prefix</kbd><kbd>></kbd> and <kbd>prefix</kbd><kbd><</kbd> in your `tmux` to test the solution (the default <kbd>prefix</kbd> is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd>).

Comment: Thank you Kamil! sorry for the delayed response, it works perfectly and only 10 lines of posix code too! thank you so much! marking this as accepted and a +1

Answer (score 0):

There is a command to switch to the last visited pane: `ctrl-b` + `;`

You can bind the `#` key (or anything you like) to switch to the last visited
tmux pane. I chose `#` because it's like how`:b#` switches to the last buffer
in vim:

```
# go to last pane (like b# in vim)
bind '#' select-pane -l
```

So you can just press you tmux prefix (by default `ctrl-b`) followed by `#`.